# Laravel 5.4 application 403 error

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, http-status-code-403

I'm experiencing this situation where my Laravel 5.4 based website suddenly gives 403 errors saying:

> Forbidden. You dont have permission to access / on this server.

But, when I clear the cookies for the website using the developer tools and refresh, it works fine.

I'm using a CentOS (CWP) + Apache + PHP + MySQL configuration where the following is my Virtual Host for the website.

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:80>
    ServerName mywebsite.lk
    ServerAlias www.mywebsite.lk
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mywebsite.lk
    DocumentRoot /home/mywebsite/public_html
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/mywebsite/public_html/cgi-bin/

    # Custom settings are loaded below this line (if any exist)
    # Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/mywebsite/mywebsite.lk/*.conf

    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir disabled
        UserDir enabled mywebsite
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
        SuexecUserGroup mywebsite mywebsite
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup mywebsite mywebsite 
        suPHP_ConfigPath /home/mywebsite 
    </IfModule>

    <Directory "/home/mywebsite/public_html">
        AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

What could be the problem? Any clues and suggestions from the experts out there are highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Possibility is that Mod_Security is causing it if installed.

Secondly, Do check your error_log file

```
tail -f /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log
```